# Regex for matching the last letter as well as the words in a sentence

Tags: java, regex

Regex for searching for words as well as returning the last character in the line.
What I have so far is this -> "[a-z]$|[a-zA-Z]+"

The text is "many???  Woooooooooooords are".

The problem is that "are" is getting matched instead of "e", the second regex pattern is getting precedence. I would like the "are" to be matched as well as "e".

Any solution for this?

Comment: You can do it with [`^(?=.*([a-z])$)|[a-zA-Z]+`](https://regex101.com/r/kW5bA4/1), but it will require  some code to get the right texts out of it. The main problem is that a regex cannot consume the text more than once. You can only *capture* overlapping text, and it is possible to do it inside lookarounds.

Comment: @Deven: What is the language you are using? I guess my regex is the best here if you plan to use 1 pattern to get what you want, just it really might be tricky for you to extract the values from captured groups.

Comment: I assume you want to find all the words, and if it just happens to be the last word in the line, to grab that with it. But, the last word won't get matched first. Just use `[a-zA-Z]*([a-zA-Z])`. The last match in a global find will contain the last letter in the last word. You can't make a distinction of lower case, and adding a `$` eos marker with it doesn't work with the other `[a-zA-Z]`  If you need the last char first, split it into two regex.

Comment: @stribizhev: You are right your answer was the most helpful here. Rest of the answers here didn't match the rest of the words in the sentence, only the "are". I also wanted to match the punctuation for finding number of setences so I came up with this [Regex](https://regex101.com/r/kW5bA4/2). But now the java code seems to return empty charcters even though the regex is correct. Needs more work...

Comment: I can help if it is Java

Comment: I added my own answer for Java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that a regex cannot consume the text more than once. You can only capture overlapping text, and it is possible to do it inside lookarounds.

Thus, you can use

```
(?s)^(?=.*([a-z])$)|[a-zA-Z]+
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kW5bA4/3)

*Explanation*:

- `(?s)` - turn on DOTALL mode so that `.` could match a newline
- `^` - start of string
- `(?=.*([a-z])$)` - a positive lookahead that checks all the string and captures the last letter. If there is trailing whitespace, replace it with `(?=.*([a-z])\\s*$)`. Note you can use `\\p{Ll}` to match a Unicode lowercase letter.
- `|` - or...
- `[a-zA-Z]+` - 1 or more letters (you can actually use `\\pL` in Java instead of this to allow matching Unicode letters)

Since it is Java, you just need to check if the first group is not `null`, and if not, you got the last letter. If the first group is null, you got a word.

```
String s = "many??? Woooooooooooords are"; 
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?s)^(?=.*([a-z])$)|[a-zA-Z]+");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
while (matcher.find()){
    if (matcher.group(1) != null) {
        System.out.println("Last letter: " + matcher.group(1));
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Word found: " + matcher.group(0)); 
    }
}
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/Nj2xZr)

Answer (score 1):

Use capture groups:

```
([a-zA-Z]+([a-z]))$
```

See [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pO1sO9/1)

For the text `many??? Woooooooooooords are`, `are` is captured in group 1 and `e` in group 2.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
([a-zA-Z]+)|([a-zA-Z]+([a-zA-Z]))$
```

This will capture all the words along with the last letter in the text. You need to use the "g" modifier (Global) along with the regex.

Answer (score 1):

At least in .NET,Java, Javascript and PHP(so..it seems a standar), Group[0] contain all the match itself, so you only need to group the last letter in the regex

[a-zA-Z]+([a-zA-Z])$

"many??? Woooooooooooords are".

Your text would go like this:

group[0] = "are"

group[1] = "e"

Answer (score 0):

This regex is twice as fast `[a-zA-Z]+($(?<=[a-z]))?`
compared to @stribizhev 's

Most notably on failure, in this case the last character is not lower case.

Benchmarks

Failure ( != [a-z]$ ):
Sample `"many??? Woooooooooooords are in the Fountain of despaR`

```
Regex1:   [a-zA-Z]+($(?<=[a-z]))?
Options:  < none >
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   8
Elapsed Time:    0.68 s,   679.77 ms,   679771 µs


Regex2:   ^(?s)(?=.*([a-z])$)|[a-zA-Z]+
Options:  < none >
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   8
Elapsed Time:    1.14 s,   1139.35 ms,   1139345 µs
```

Success ( == [a-z]$ ):
Sample `"many??? Woooooooooooords are in the Fountain of despar`

```
Regex1:   [a-zA-Z]+($(?<=[a-z]))?
Options:  < none >
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   8
Elapsed Time:    0.68 s,   678.97 ms,   678965 µs


Regex2:   ^(?s)(?=.*([a-z])$)|[a-zA-Z]+
Options:  < none >
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   9
Elapsed Time:    0.72 s,   717.28 ms,   717276 µs
```